# How to find equivalent resistance of this mixed circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance, homework

Find equivalent resistance, the current in R5, voltage across R2 and power of R10.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjdWGL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Actually, I don't know if my attempt is right. So, you would point out where there are mistakes, pleased.

R10 and R11 are in parallel: R10||11, also, R6 and R7 are in parallel: R6||7. Then R10||11 and R12 are in parallel: (R10||11)||12, then R9 and (R10||11)||12 are in series: R9+(10||11)||12. Then R9+(10||11)||12 and R13 are in parallel (R9+(10||11)||12)||13), then R1, R2, and (R9+(10||11)||12)||13) are in series: R1+2+(9+(10||11)||12)||13)...

And so on, until the circuit becomes this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZBIoK.png)</sup>

Then are R5 and R3 in parallel? If this is right I can continue myself. Another question, how to get current in R5 and voltage of R2? Kirchhoff's Rules ?

Comment: Are the two ends of R5 and R3 connected to the same two nodes? If yes, then they're in parallel.

Comment: Are you familiar with converting between Thevenin and Norton equivalents?  This would simplify the analysis considerably.

Comment: yea r5, r3 are parallel ! Then the ckt simplifies :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are many techniques that you could use to find the currents and voltages in the circuit, including the node-voltage method and the mesh-current method. In general, these methods will all rely on Kirchhoff's laws and Ohm's law.

Since you have only a resistor network and a single source you can combine resistors until you have a single resistor and the source...then find the current being provided by the source. That must be the same current as is flowing through R4, so now you know the voltage across R4. Work backwards through your simplifications of the resistor network, finding more detailed current and voltage information as you work your way back to the original circuit.